# saving document in mongo using node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Create and Save a Record of a Model

My code:

```
var mongoose= require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect("****");

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on(‘error’, console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

var personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name : String,
    age : Number,
    favoriteFoods :[String]
});

var Person = mongoose.model(‘Person’, personSchema);

var createAndSavePerson = function(done) {
 var mr = new Person({
    name: 'Mrdude',
    age: 22,
    favoriteFoods: ['Ice Creame', 'Grills']})

  mr.save(function(err, mr) {
    if(err) return console.error(err);
  });
  done(null, mr);
};
```

i am not able to find this error

i am getting “Cannot read property ‘name’ of null” error

please point where i am wrong

Comment: Which line is this error coming from?  Could you screenshot the error? :)

Comment: Sashi, it is coming from this line `if(err) return console.error(err);` probably

Comment: Try removing ';' before done and replace it with '.'

Comment: @SyedKashanAli  still That won't work

Comment: thanks @KuchBhi for pointing to the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var mongoose= require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect("****");

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on(‘error’, console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

var personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name : String,
age : Number,
favoriteFoods :[String]
});

var Person = mongoose.model(‘Person’, personSchema);

var createAndSavePerson = function(done) {
var mr = new Person({
name: 'Mrdude',
age: 22,
favoriteFoods: ['Ice Creame', 'Grills']})

mr.save(function(err,data) {
if(err)
  {
    done(err);
  }
else
{
    done(null, data);
}
});

};
```

this is working fine now i made a mistake in call back function so the properties was not accessible. i was returning "mr" which was not right.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add these lines :

```
personSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  // get the current date
   var currentDate = new Date();

  // change the updated_at field to current date
   this.updatedAt = currentDate;

  // if created_at doesn't exist, add to that field
  if (!this.createdAt) {
    this.createdAt = currentDate;
  }

  next();
});

  const newPerson = new Person();

  let name ='x'
  let family = 'y'
  .
  .
  .
  Object.assign(newPerson, req.body, {
   name: name,

  });

 newPerson.save((err, log) => {
    if (err) return next(err)
  });
```

Comment: Doesn't make sense why he needs to add the above lines? can you elaborate?

Comment: he need to define save

Comment: I don't care if you judge or not,  I just try to help... might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You've placed wrong position of callback function.

Your `done` is callback function which is passed to `createAndSavePerson`, so it should be call when `save` is completed.

```
var mongoose= require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect("****");

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on(‘error’, console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

var personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name : String,
    age : Number,
    favoriteFoods :[String]
});

var Person = mongoose.model(‘Person’, personSchema);

var createAndSavePerson = function(done) {
 var mr = new Person({
    name: 'Mrdude',
    age: 22,
    favoriteFoods: ['Ice Creame', 'Grills']})

  mr.save(function(err, mr) {
    return done(err, mr);
  });

  // Wrong position
  // done(null, mr); 
};


// Call function when you need
createAndSave((err, data) => {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  else console.log(data);
})
```

Comment: LOL :) I didn't notice you had the answer for yourself

Comment: yesterday i was facing that issue but after getting i thought to post , by the way thanks for noticing my issue